# scroll inside fixed div element with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a fixed position sidebar with some containers inside it with overflow:auto, so they can scroll separately from the body, what I'd like to do is scroll the element .left as the body scrolls.

I can get it working the opposite way, ie, .left is scrolled and the body moves as it's scrolling (see jsfiddle).

```
$(function(){

    $('.left').scroll(function(){
        $('body').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());    
    })

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8Krz/403/

What I want to achieve is when body is scrolled, .left scrolls down too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(function () {

    $('.left').scroll(function () {
        $(window).scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $('.left').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    })

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g8Krz/404/

If you want you can also do scrolling to same percentage of height not to absolute value of `scrollTop()`.

**Edit**

This is percentage scrolling implementation. Not the best, but it works and shows you the general idea.

```
$(function(){

    var $window = $(window);
    var $body = $('body');
    var $left = $('.left');

    var windowScrollHeight = $body.get(0).scrollHeight;
    var leftScrollHeight= $left.get(0).scrollHeight;

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var relativeScroll = windowScrollTop / windowScrollHeight;
        var leftScrollTop = relativeScroll * leftScrollHeight;

        $left.scrollTop(leftScrollTop);
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N3GR8/1/

Comment: How would one do it to the percentage of height? EDIT:- the problem with using the $(window) function is that when the .left element is scrolled to the bottom it repeatedly jumps back to the top over and over again. http://jsfiddle.net/g8Krz/406/

Comment: Give me a moment to do it.

Comment: The only problem I see with it, is the bug with the .left when you try to scroll that after scrolling the body, trying to think how to mitigate that.

Comment: And the problem with repeatedly jumping back to the top, if you scroll left sidebar to bottom, is pretty obvious. If inner scroll reach it constrain, browser is scrolling outer(parent) scroll, and this triggers scroll event which we bound to.

Comment: Yeah, maybe the only way to stop that is to have .left scrolling the body element too.

Comment: Maybe you can wrap your body content in another div with `max-height' set and in that case scrolling left side will not trigger scrolling right side, when it reaches its constrains.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Jan, I'll mark your answer as correct then update mine if I decide to do anything different.